# How to use service worker library (MSW) with Parcel bundler

Tags: javascript, node.js, service-worker, parceljs, msw

I have a small TypeScript React project that I bundle using Parcel. I wanted to add MSW for mocking server requests, but I have troubles getting it to work.

I have a very minimalistic Parcel setup:

```json
"scripts": {
  "start": "parcel index.html",
  "build": "parcel build index.html"
},
```

And as for the MSW, everything is done according to their [documentation](https://mswjs.io/docs/getting-started/integrate/browser). Here's how the service-worker is initiated:

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  const { worker } = require("./mocks/browser")
  worker.start()
}
```

The same exact implementation works perfectly when bundling with Webpack. But in Parcel it results in following errors in the console:

`The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').`

`[MSW] Failed to register a Service Worker: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:1234/') with script ('http://localhost:1234/mockServiceWorker.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').`

Is there a way to get it to work?

Answer (score 4):

Solution: `npx msw init dist`

Turns out I run `npx msw init` with `public` which works for `Create-React-App`, and not with `dist` as I should when using Parcel.